# What GitHub projects automatically run clang-tidy as part of their continuous integration?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, static-analysis, clang-tidy

I am curious to know to what extent linters such as `clang-tidy` are in day-to-day use in large projects, as a part of a continuous integration process. Is there a way I can search GitHub for projects that run a certain tool, such as `clang-tidy`, automatically on every commit or pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a custom search on GitHub, for example, try [this](https://github.com/search?q=clang-tidy+language%3Abash&type=code) search query: `clang-tidy language:bash`.

Most projects probably use shell scripts written in bash to run `clang-tidy`. Using `language:bash` you can easily filter them to find an example suitable for your project. You can view all the available search keywords in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code).